# Finding and replacing a specific object in priority queue

Tags: java, queue

With a list I would usually be able to find an element by doing something like this:

```
int index = open.indexOf(object);
if(index != -1){
   open.set(index, neighbour);
}
```

Is there a replacement/workarounds for priority queues?

I have:

`PriorityQueue<State> open = createQ();`

Comment: if you're using a priority queue there is no method to allow you to replace an object with another one. you will have poll() all the objects, add them to a list, then remove the one you want and then add() or offer() them back into your priority queue. Make sure you call contains() beforehand to ensure that the object you want to remove is present in the queue

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
pq.add("test1");

// removes object and return true if it was removed
if (pq.remove("test1")) {
    // adds element in natural ordering
    pq.add("test2");
}
```